# Pi hangs after using kodi for about a minute

Tags: kodi

when I start kodi on my pi after a minute the screen goes black and the pi crashes. Please help!
Read the ERRORLOG: http://pastebin.com/CeAnrH0W

Comment: please add the error message to your question, not as a link to a 3rd party service.

Comment: `"after a minute"` - so, all you do is start kodi, and do absolutely nothing for a minute, and the pi crashes, not just kodi, but the pi iteself?

Comment: @JaromandaX yes i use kodi for about a minute and the screen goes black and the pi hangs

Comment: Are you overclocking at all?

Comment: @JaromandaX Yes, I'm overclocking at turbo.

Comment: try without overclocking - out of several piB's for instance, I found they all have different maximum rates they can handle. I'm assuming you DONT have a Pi2 or Pi3

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I changed the overclock to NORMAL mode and Kodi worked fine after that.